# Kivy code crashes while running it on kivy launcher

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The following code runes fine on windows but when i'm trying running it on kivy launcher it crashes immediately.
There is a kv file as well as the script.
I've been trying to solve this problem for quite same time unfortunately with no success.
Thx for any help.

## python script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.3')
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Painter(Widget):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AnotherScreen(Screen):

    pass


class AnotherScreen2(Screen):
    pass


class AnotherScreen3(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("showcase.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
            return presentation

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MainApp().run()
```

## kv file

Which the python script loads
name : showcase.kv

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
    AnotherScreen2:
    AnotherScreen3:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"

    FloatLayout:
        Painter
        Button:
            text: "1"
            on_release: app.root.current = "other"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

        Button:
            text: "2"
            on_release: app.root.current = "power"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}

        Button:
            text: "3"
            on_release: app.root.current = "tube"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"x": .5, "top": 1}
        
<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "other"
    
    FloatLayout:
    
        Painter
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            text: "Back Home"
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
            pos_hint: {"right":0.5, "top":1}

<AnotherScreen2>:
    name: "power"

    FloatLayout:
        Painter
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            text: "Back Home"
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
            pos_hint: {"right":0.5, "top":1}


<AnotherScreen3>:
    name: "tube"

    FloatLayout:
        Painter
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            text: "Back Home"
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
            pos_hint: {"right":0.5, "top":1}
```

Comment: I think launcher is outdated

Comment: And why require 1.1.3?

Comment: @el3ien Thanks for replying.The launcher works just fine with the examples I got online so I don't think that's the problem .any suggestions?